# EE Built in contact form

Tags: email-contact-form

I'm using the built in contact form, but the only element that gets emailed is the message.  Nothing else.

```
{exp:email:contact_form user_recipients="no" recipients="nick@pixelsandcode.co.uk" charset="utf-8" form_class="form form--full"}
    <p id = "ajax-message"></p>
    <fieldset class="controls">
        <label for="from" class="controls__label">Your Email:</label><br />
        <input class="controls__control" type="text" id="from" name="from" size="40" maxlength="35" value="{member_email}" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="controls">
        <label for="budget" class="controls__label">Your Budget:</label><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="budget[]" value="--Your Budget--" />
        <input class="" type="range" name="budget" id="budget" min="1000" max="10000" step="1000" value="3000" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" list="ticks" />
        <datalist id="ticks">
            <option>1000</option>
            <option>2000</option>
            <option>3000</option>
            <option>4000</option>
            <option>5000</option>
            <option>6000</option>
            <option>7000</option>
            <option>8000</option>
            <option>9000</option>
            <option>10000</option>
        </datalist>
        <output for="range" id="your_budget" class="output">£3000</output>
        <script>
            function numberWithCommas(x) {
                return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            }
            function outputUpdate(amount) {
                document.querySelector('#your_budget').value = "£"+numberWithCommas(amount);
            }

        </script>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="controls">
        <label for="message" class="controls__label">Message:</label><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="message[]" value="--Message--" />
        <textarea class="controls__control" id="message" name="message" rows="18" cols="40"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="controls">
        <label for="extra" class="controls__label">Extra:</label><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="extra[]" value="--Extra--" />
        <textarea class="controls__control" id="extra" name="extra" rows="18" cols="40"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="controls">
        <input name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit Form' class="btn btn--primary" />
    </fieldset>
{/exp:email:contact_form}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The Email module doesn't know what to do with arbitrary POST data, it can only recognize fields that it is looking for. To build an email from multiple fields, use only the `message` field, but [as an array](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/email/contact_form.html#message). e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="message[]" />
<textarea name="message[]"></textarea>
```

Comment: ah I see.  Let me try that.

Comment: Ok, I think I am still confused.

This is my code now:

`<fieldset class="controls">
 <label for="message" class="controls__label">Message:</label><br />
 <input type="hidden" name="message[]" value="--Message--" />
 <textarea class="controls__control" id="message" name="message" rows="18" cols="40"></textarea>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="controls">
 <label for="extra" class="controls__label">Extra:</label><br />
 <input type="hidden" name="message[]" value="--Extra--" />
 <textarea class="controls__control" id="extra" name="extra" rows="18" cols="40"></textarea>
</fieldset>`

not working.

Comment: Your textarea needs a name of `message[]` as well instead of `message`.

Comment: Ok that works now.  It's quite basic isn't it?  The email form is only going to me so I don't mind the lack of styling, but not sure any of my clients would be too happy with it.

But all good for now.

Comment: Well you can use that technique with any of the fields you want to use to build the message, not just those, complete apart from styling. Just a note that `datalist` I don't think is supported in Safari. http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist

Comment: Thanks, surprised it's not working in Safari, but it's only aesthetics.  Do you know also if it's possible to redirect to a thank you page that is not default styling in EE?

Comment: That interim page can't be entirely bypassed; EE redirects there so that refreshing the browser on the landing page doesn't resubmit the form. But you can control the length of time that notice appears as well as where it lands. If you use the [return parameter](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/email/contact_form.html#return) with a segment like `/thank-you`, you could use [segment conditionals](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/url_segments.html) on the landing page (even if it's the same as the email form) to display a custom message.

Comment: Ok, not really sure that is ideal for me.